# Set MS SQL login roles in different cultures

Tags: sql-server, powershell, culture

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that allows me to set server roles for logins in different cultures.

More specifically, I want to grant the **`sysadmin`** role to the logins **`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`** and **`NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`**. Up until now, I have done so using an SQL script. However, I found out the hard way that this script doesn't work on German installations of windows, since the two logins are called **`NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM`** and **`NT-AUTORITÄT\Netzwerkdienst`** there respectively.

I have already figured out that the SIDs for these logins are **`S-1-5-18`** and **`S-1-5-20`** respectively, but I don't know how I can use that to my advantage yet.

Here's the SQL script I've been using so far:

```
PRINT 'Granting sysadmin role to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM...'

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT name
    FROM master.sys.server_principals 
    WHERE IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin', name) = 1 
    AND name LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
)
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember
    @loginame = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', @rolename = N'sysadmin'

PRINT 'Granting sysadmin role to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE...'

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT name
    FROM master.sys.server_principals 
    WHERE IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin', name) = 1 
    AND name LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
)
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember
    @loginame = N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
```

As mentioned above, that has the problem that it doesn't work for cultures other than English. I have already tried creating a PowerShell script for this using SQLPS and SqlServer, but didn't make much progress there.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
Kira Resari

Comment: Does `SELECT SUSER_SNAME(0x010100000000000512000000), SUSER_SNAME(0x010100000000000514000000)` return the expected names? You could use that in dynamic SQL. However, my advice is to avoid all of that and create your own local group with a known name, grant SQL permissions on the group, and add any accounts you want to get sysadmin permission to that instead. This avoids encoding any sort of account name in your script.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142166/grant-sysadmin-permissions-to-nt-authority-system#142169

Comment: _"BUILTIN\administrators and Local System (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) are not automatically provisioned in the sysadmin fixed server role."_ - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500459(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Note also in particular that giving `NETWORK SERVICE` sysadmin permissions is a bad idea. Lots of services run under that account and most do not even have any need to access SQL Server, let alone as administrator. The account is explicitly intended to have fewer permissions than a full-blown system account. If possible, run your services under specific accounts instead (like virtual service accounts of the form `NT SERVICE\MyAccount`, which require no password management). Giving `SYSTEM` permission is not as harmful, but at the same time also not as useful.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Thank you, that SUSER_SNAME(0x01010000000000051*000000) was the critical piece of information that I needed to put together a working solution. Actually, I'm planning to change our setup to work with a role less risky than sysadmin, but for now, it is good to just have a working configuration that we can use for testing. Thank you very much! I've now added my fix as an answer to that post, but I would like to give you credit for your help. If you post this fix as your answer, I'll be sure to vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jeroen Mostert's comment, I was able to piece together the following solution which now works on both English and German installations of Windows. I am pretty sure it will also work on other cultures:

```
DECLARE @user_name_nt_authority_system NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @user_name_nt_authority_network_service NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @user_name_nt_authority_system = SUSER_SNAME(0x010100000000000512000000)
SET @user_name_nt_authority_network_service = SUSER_SNAME(0x010100000000000514000000)

PRINT 'Granting sysadmin role to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM...'

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT name
    FROM master.sys.server_principals 
    WHERE IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin', name) = 1 
    AND name LIKE @user_name_nt_authority_system 
)
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember
    @loginame = @user_name_nt_authority_system, @rolename = N'sysadmin'

PRINT 'Granting sysadmin role to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE...'

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT name
    FROM master.sys.server_principals 
    WHERE IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin', name) = 1 
    AND name LIKE @user_name_nt_authority_network_service
)
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember
    @loginame = @user_name_nt_authority_network_service, @rolename = N'sysadmin'
```